# How can i backup a ESXi VM to an attached USB storage

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I have `Esx` installed on `IBM 3450` server.

I want to make backups of my VM on attached USB device in server.

My network speed is very less so i can't backup and copy through network.

Is it possible through any software

Comment: Doesn't ESXi allow backing up a VM via the WebUI?

Comment: This [was impossible some time ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/61644/can-you-use-a-usb-hard-drive-in-esxi/761852#761852), I believe, it is still impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Free [Veeam](http://www.veeam.com/virtual-machine-backup-solution-free.html) is pretty good, it allows you to VeeamZip an Adhoc backup to a network share. 
The full version is even better. 30 day trial on the full version, once trial is over the product rolls over to the free edition.

Free Edition does have a number of limitations, including:

- Full backups of individual VMs only—no scheduled, incremental or multi-VM 
  backups
- No vPower® capabilities (however, you can import VeeamZIP™ backups into the 
  paid editions and use vPower capabilities there)
- No VM replication
- No scripting

A [backup repository](http://helpcenter.veeam.com/backup/70/vsphere/backup_repository.html?zoom_highlightsub=usb) is a location used by Veeam Backup & Replication jobs to store backup files, copies of VMs and metadata for replicated VMs. Technically, a backup repository is a folder on the backup storage. By assigning different repositories to jobs and limiting the number of parallel jobs for each one, you can balance the load across your backup infrastructure.

**Veeam Backup Target**

Backup can be performed to the following disk-based storage targets:

- Local (internal) storage of the backup repository server.
- Direct Attached Storage (DAS) connected to the backup repository
  server, including external USB/eSATA drives and raw device mapping
  (RDM) volumes.
- Storage Area Network (SAN). Backup repository server must be
  connected into the SAN fabric via hardware HBA or software iSCSI
  initiator, and the corresponding volumes must be seen in the
  Microsoft Windows Disk Management snap-in.
- Network Attached Storage (NAS) able to represent itself as CIFS (SMB)
  share (direct operation), or NFS share (must be mounted on a Linux
  backup repository server).

Comment: Also you have to use a minimum of a licensed version of ESXi for Veeam. The free version of ESxi won't work.